# firefox issues in document.forms[0].submit()

Tags: forms, firefox3.6

I have a form which I want to submit on bodyLoad.

I have written `document.forms[0].submit()` which works fine with IE 9 and Chrome 14 but same is not working in FF 3.6.23.

Any ideas? Is this a known issue with FF?

I have tried other options like `document.form_name.submit()` and `document.getElementById('form_id').submit()` but nothing works with FF.

The error I am getting in FF is

> `document.forms[0]` is undefined

This is what I have written in the view (CakePHP 1.2.6):

```
<?php $this->layout = 'blank'; ?>

<?php e($form->create('Mymodel', array('name'=>'myform', 'url'=>'gohere'))); ?>

<?php e($form->hidden('name', array('value'=>$name))); ?>

<?php e($form->end()); ?>

<script language="javascript">
document.forms[0].submit();
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your code or a link to the page.

Comment: added my code above .. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work in Firefox, since the page isn't fully loaded yet.

Eliminate

`document.forms[0].submit();`

and set

`<body onLoad="document.forms[0].submit();">`

Be careful not to point `<form>` to the current page, as it would cause an endless loop.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. Is this documented somewhere in FF. I mean where can I find all such know issues for FF, etc. ?

Comment: I was wrong. I've changed my answer to display the actual facts. For bugs in Firefox, visit [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

Comment: okie... so the setTimeout() thing worked because the form is loaded by that time. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The javascript code may be executed before the form is actually loaded. That's why Firefox can't find document.forms[0]. You have to make sure your page is ready before executing javascript. With JQuery, you do it with $(document).ready()

Comment: Thanks WilQu. I will check how to do this without jQuery [ because i am not using it ].